# Disable close icons on editor tabs?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.3-rio

After upgrading from Delphi Tokyo 10.2.x to Rio 10.3.1, the tabs for the files in the editor now have close icons:

[image]

<sup>Close icons in Delphi Rio 10.3.1 - Mouseover makes others visible/active</sup>

[image]

<sup>No close icons in Delphi Tokyo 10.2.x</sup>

Especially with shorter file names, I regularly click on the little x when I want to switch to a specific file in the editor.
If the file has pending edits, I can click Cancel to stop it from closing, but often I find myself having to reopen it.

It's a bit of a nuisance.

Can these close icons be disabled in the IDE?

Answer (score 2):

> Can these close icons be disabled in the IDE?

No.

What you can do is to completely disable new themes. But that will require editing registry.

Head to following registry key

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0\Theme
```

and change following key-value entry:

```
Key: Enabled
Value: 0
```

If you wish to enable themes again just change Value back to 1.

**Note:** Unthemed IDE is no longer officially supported so you may have issues while using such IDE.

Comment: It seems you always need a hack to make things work right in the Delphi IDE, I really wish that the Language server they are making would let us use visual studio code with some plugin for the form designer.